# Parsing php array in python

Tags: php, python, parsing

I'm getting a PHP array from a web page (as a string).
It looks like :

```
Array
(
[k1] => Array
    (
        [a] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [age] => 60
            )

        [b] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [age] => 30
            )

    )

[k2] => v2
)
```

I want to parse it in python.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks,
Rivka

Edit:
This is really not a json, like a few people commented.
Thanks for the comments, and I updated the question.

Comment: what do you mean by parsing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061274/getting-started-with-json)

Comment: That is not json - that is php

Comment: This is not JSON. You'd have to do a `json_encode($array);` in PHP to get proper JSON.

Comment: That's no JSON... If it was, it shouldn't matter where it comes from. JSON is JSON is JSON.

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: Where are u getting it from? O.o

Answer (score 10):

That's not JSON, that's just how PHP prints arrays. If you want to create JSON of the array, check out [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for PHP. Then use [Python's JSON library](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) (or here for [py3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html?highlight=json#json)) to read it.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you are using print_r on array to get that output. This is a visual representation of array only, you can't really parse it. For example:

```
array('Array'.PHP_EOL."\t(".PHP_EOL."            [0] => test".PHP_EOL."\t)")
```

will look exactly like

```
array(array('test'));
```

You should use some real serializing function to do what you want(json,serialize etc.);